# Check for any Syntax error in ACE web editor

Tags: jquery, json, ace-editor

I want to check if the code written in the ACE editor has any syntax error or not. I want to do this for doing a basic check for JSON that i want the users to edit. so that they don't save any bad JSON.

What's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually quite simple to check. First of all make sure you have programming language syntax highlight in place:

```
this.editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/json");
```

This will make sure that any syntax related notes are shown as an editor annotation. Then get the editor annotations using this:

```
editor.getSession().getAnnotations();
```

This will give you an array of editor annotation object e.g.:

```
{
    column: 2,
    row: 40,
    type: "error",
    text: "Expected ',' instead of '"'"
}
```

Just check in these objects if any one of them has a `type: "error"`. That's it.